# Prove: $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|xy>1\}$ is open

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Prove: $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|xy>1\}$

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be defined as follow: $f(x,y)=xy$

Moreover $D=f^{-1}(1,\infty)$

The preimage $(1,\infty)$ is an open interval and therefore open.
$f$ is continuous as a product of two linear (and in particular continues functions) and therefore $D$ is open

Is this proof valid?

Comment: Yes, it is a valid proof. Also, you can take a look at my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437337/find-the-limit-points-of-a-x-y-in-mathbbr2-xy-1-subset-math/1457732#1457732), in which I solve the problem directly (that is, proving that every point of $D$ is an interior point of $D$ by giving the appropiate open balls around each point). However, the idea is essentially the same, because if you look carefully at my answer you'll see that it is continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the proof is correct, but I won't call $(1,\infty)$ image.

Comment: changed to preimage

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more geometric approach.

Let $P(a,b)\in D$. Define $d_P(x)$ to be the distance from $(x,1/x)$ to $P$. Check that $d_P:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ is continuous (it's differentiable on its domain).  Let $\epsilon>0$ be the minimum value of $d_P$ (it is non-trivial to find an algebraic expressionthe exact value, as it requires finding the root of a quartic polynomial).  Let $B$ be the ball of radius $\epsilon/2$ centered at $P$.  Then $B$ does not meet the boundary of $D$ and, since $B$ is connected but $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \partial D$ is not, it also does not meet $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \overline{D}$. So there is an open ball about $P$ contained in $D$. So $P$ is an interior point of $D$. Thus $D$ is open, since all of its points are interior points.

[image: $D$ is shown in blue.]